# What is the largest complete subspace of $(\mathbb{Q}, |\cdot|)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For example $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}\cup \{0\}$ is a complete subspace of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I am having trouble writing out the largest (in the sense of "$\subset$") complete subspace in $(\mathbb{Q}, |\cdot|)$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Largest in what sense? $\mathbb Z$ is complete and has the same cardinality as $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: There isn't a largest complete subspace: if $S$ is any complete subspace, $x \in S$ and $y \notin S$, then the translation $S + (y-x)$ is also a complete subspace, and it is not a subspace of $S$. All you could hope for is the existence of a maximal subspace.

Comment: there is no largest one, you could always add one more sequence converging to a point that wasn't already in the space.

Comment: In the sense of "$\subset$". And Nvm, I don't think Zorn's lemma can apply here.

Comment: @Xiao: Zorn's lemma doesn't work here! The union of a chain of complete subspaces isn't necessarily a complete subspace! For example, $$\{3\} \subseteq \{ 3, 3.1 \} \subseteq \{ 3, 3.1, 3.14 \} \subseteq \ldots $$ In fact, this chain doesn't have an upper bound at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you can prove the existence by Zorn's lemma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot apply Zorn's lemma because Zorn's lemma says something about chains, and here if you take a chain of complete subspaces, the union of the chain need not be complete. For example list $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$,and let $F_n=\{q_k:k\le n\}$. Then each $F_n$ is complete (even finite) and these $F_n$ form an increasing chain, yet the union of this chain is $\Bbb Q$, which is not complete.